# ICESat/GLAS coordinate system conversion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, idl

I have to import ICESat GLAS14 product data into ArcGIS. I managed to export into an ASCII file the binary GLAS data using NGAT tool, but the coordinates system are in an uncommon format (TOPEX/Poseidon).
Apparently they provide an IDL script to convert the coordinates, but I can't get it work.
The tools are listed here: http://nsidc.org/data/icesat/tools.html

Does anyone have experience working with ICESat/GLAS product and can help me getting this points in WGS84 coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

from what I know, Icesat products in the poles are in the "NSIDC Sea Ice Polar polar stereographic" projection. Depending on which pole your are, you could use the EPSG code with [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to reproject your data.

Arctic : EPSG 3413

Antarctic EPSG 3976